# How to to skip invalid XML file with incomplete closing tags in PHP

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I am using **PHP DOM Xpath** to read XML files. In some cases tags are not properly closed like below

```
<data>
   <name> value </name>
   <address
```

I have following code to **check if XML is valid**

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();

if(!$doc->load(test.xml))  
 {  
      foreach (libxml_get_errors() as $error) 
      {
          print_r($error);
      }
        libxml_clear_errors();
 }
 else
 {
     $valid_xml = 'y';      
 }

 if($valid_xml=='y')
 // then process XML
 else
 // skip and take next file
```

but I am getting below errors at line **if(!$doc->load(test.xml))**

```
Message: DOMDocument::load(): Couldn't find end of Start Tag AdjustmentsToReconcile

Message: DOMDocument::load(): Premature end of data in tag
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there. Try adding the command libxml_use_internal_errors(true); before everything to tell PHP not to throw errors but to cache them for you to iterate through as your code is doing.

Answer (score 1):

That should helps you:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc = new DOMDocument();

$valid_xml = true;
if(!$doc->load(test.xml))
{  
    $valid_xml = (count(libxml_get_errors()) === 0);
    libxml_clear_errors();
}

if($valid_xml)
// then process XML
else
// skip and take next file
```

libxml_use_internal_errors is the key.